# JQuery clone last element from each list row

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm trying to clone **last element from each list row**. I can clone rows(i need to clone first element in this case), but I can't clone last `span` from each `li`. Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="elements">
    <li>
        <span>Span 1</span>
        <span>Span 2</span>
        <span>Span 3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Span 4</span>
        <span>Span 5</span>
        <span>Span 6</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="new_row">Add new row</a>
<a href="#" class="new_column">Add new column</a>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.new_row').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ul = $(this).prev('.elements');

    var new_data= $("li", ul).eq(0).clone();
    new_data.appendTo(ul);
});
$('.new_column').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li').each(function(){
        $('span:last').clone();
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vPDpH/

I would appreciate any help. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are cloning the element but not doing anything with it ..

Also you **need to clone the last span in the context of current li**. Otherwise it will clone the **last span in the HTML irrespective of where it** is

```
$('.new_row').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ul = $(this).prev('.elements');

    var new_data= $("li", ul).eq(0).clone();
    new_data.appendTo(ul);
});
$('.new_column').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li').each(function(){
       var new_data= $('span:last', this).clone();
        new_data.appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPDpH/1/)**

Comment: ur first answer was not working. but this time it works. nice!

Comment: Uhh, you're right, forgot to append the new cloned element. Stupid mistake. Thank you for help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative

Javascript

```
$(".new_row").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elements = $(e.target).siblings(".elements").first();

    elements.append($("li", elements).first().clone());
});

$(".new_column").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li", $(e.target).siblings(".elements").first()).each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).append($("span", element).last().clone());
    });
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/uLSe8/)

Comment: Yes but in my case I'm cloning first row and last column. Your code clone last row and not first. ;)

Comment: Oops, easy mistake, and fixed.